# Unable to convert IEnumerable<TEntity> to TCollection

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, repository

I've defined the following interfaces:

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey, TCollection>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
    where TCollection: IEnumerable<TEntity>

{
    TCollection GetAll();
}

public interface IReadOnlyRepository<TEntity, TKey> :
    IReadOnlyRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey, IEnumerable<TEntity>>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
{ }

// there is also "ILazyReadOnlyRepository" where TCollection
// is IQueryable<T>..
```

Now I can't return a `IEnumerable<TEntity>` in my implementation because `IEnumerable<TEntity>` doesn't seem to be convertible to `TCollection`.

```
// basic repository impl for NHibernate
public abstract class NHibernateReadOnlyRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey, TCollection> 
    : IReadOnlyRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey, TCollection>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
    where TCollection : IEnumerable<TEntity>
{

    public TCollection GetAll()
    {
          // doesn't work...
          return _session.QueryOver<TEntity>().List();
    }
```

As far as I can see, the method returns a `IList<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so this should obviously work? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: How should this work? `TCollection` could also be `List<TEntity>`, in that case you would be casting a `IList<TEntity>` to `List<TEntity>`. Thats not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the generic argument `TCollection`.  The use of a generic argument is a way of saying that the user of this interface should be able to define what that type is, in this case what type is returned by this method.

Clearly that's a problem for you.  Your implementations of the method need to unconditionally return an `IEnumerable`, not an unknown type specified by the caller.  Just remove that generic argument to accomplish that.

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

Comment: But that way I can specify an interface that is expected to return a IQueryable for e.g. a lazy repository implementation.

Comment: @xvdiff Then define it to return an `IQueryable`.